# Pular linha em tabela HTML/CSS/PHP

Tags: php, html, css

Olá!

Bom Dia, Boa tarde ou Boa Noite!

Estou com um probleminha a um tempo e só percebi agora (depois de umas 10 páginas desse tipo), tenho uma página que lista todos os dados da tabela sobre placas (listarplacas.php) e nela é impresso todos os resultados de acordo com o comando "SELECT * FROM ESTOQUECVISUAL", o meu problema é que como a tabela impressa possui 'títulos' (TIPO, TRANSACAO, TAMANHO, QUANTIDADE) o primeiro resultado é sempre ocultado pelos títulos, como posso fazer para exibir os resultados da consulta a partir da segunda linha?

Imagens que ajudam a descrever o problema:

**CONSULTA NO BANCO USANDO O COMANDO ACIMA**
[image: CONSULTA NO BANCO USANDO O COMANDO ACIMA]

**CONSULTA NO BANCO COM O MESMO COMANDO ACIMA MAS IMPRESSO COM PHP/CSS/HTML**
[image: CONSULTA NO BANCO COM O MESMO COMANDO ACIMA MAS IMPRESSO COM PHP/CSS/HTML]

Se repararem o primeiro resultado "é comido" pelos titulos (TIPO, TRANSACAO, TAMANHO, QUANTIDADE) da tabela, as vezes é um errinho besta que não estou percebendo, se puderem me ajudar!!

CÓDIGO DA PÁGINA:  listarplacas.php

```
    <CDOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>ESTOQUE DE PLACAS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo/estilo.css">
    </head>
<body>

    <?php
    include "config/cabecalho.php";
    ?>


    <div class="container">
        <div class="titulo-principal">ESTOQUE DE PLACAS</div>
            <button value="VOLTAR" class="botao" onClick="history.go(-1)"><img src="imagens/iconevoltar.png" class="img-botao"> VOLTAR</button>
            <button value="ATUALIZAR" class="botao" onClick="history.go(0)"><img src="imagens/iconeatl.png" class="img-botao"> ATUALIZAR</button>
            <br>
            <br>
            <hr>
            <br>
<?php

    include "config/conectar.php";

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM ESTOQUECVISUAL";

                $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao,$sql);

                if(mysqli_num_rows($resultado)>0){

                    $linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);

                //TABELA ESTOQUECVISUAL (PLACAS - comunicação visual)
                $id = $linha["ID"];
                $tipo = $linha["TIPO"];
                $transacao = $linha["TRANSACAO"];
                $tamanho = $linha["TAMANHO"];
                $quantidade = $linha["QUANTIDADE"];

                }
?>
<table border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse" width="60%">
                <tr class="cabecalho-tabela">
                  <td width="20%">TIPO</td>
                  <td>TRANSAÇÃO</td>
                  <td>TAMANHO</td>
                  <td>QUANTIDADE</td>
                  <td width='2%'></td>
                </tr>

<?php
            while($linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
                $tipo = $linha['TIPO'];
                $transacao = $linha['TRANSACAO'];
                $tamanho = $linha['TAMANHO'];
                $quantidade = $linha['QUANTIDADE'];
                echo"

                    <tr>
                      <td>$tipo</td>
                      <td>$transacao</td>
                      <td>$tamanho</td>
                      <td>$quantidade</td>
                      <td><a href='alterarestoqueplacas.php?id=$id'><img src='imagens/iconeditar.png' /></a></td>
                    </tr>

                ";
            }
     ?>
            </table>
                  <br>
                  <hr>
                  <br>
                  <br>
    <?php
    include "config/rodape.php";
    ?>

    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Se faltar coisa eu adiciono posteriormente, sou leigo no assunto...

Comment: Seu código está errado está usando duas vezes o mysqli_fetch_assoc só é necessário o segundo dentro do seu While. Na primeira chamada ele retorna a primeira linha de resultado para as variaveis definidas, na segunda chamada ele começa do segundo resultado em diante. Não há necessidade de carregar o resultado de sua query dentro das variaveis se não utiliza. Esse seu bloco de instrução if(mysqli_num_rows($resultado)>0) é completamente desnecessário.

Comment: Nossa, muitissimo obrigado!! Era exatamente isso!!

Comment: De nada Irmão! Eu ia postar uma resposta completa mas fiquei com medo de confundir você. O que acontece é que o mysqli_fetch_assoc vai abrir um manipulador do resultado obtidos em sua query, internamente existe uma variável contador que incrementa quantos registros foram lidos, como chamou duas vezes, essa variável interna da função já tinha sido incrementada da primeira vez. Por isso que na segunda vez que chamou mysqli_fetch_assoc,  ele começava a partir do segundo registro obtido.

Answer (score 1):

Não esta mostrando a primeira linha porque você está consumindo ela no *if* e não esta usando, dando *echo*.

Basta excluir esse *if*, ou apenas seguir no *while*/tabela se o *select* trazer resultado.

listarplacas.php

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>ESTOQUE DE PLACAS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo/estilo.css">
    </head>
<body>

    <?php
    include "config/cabecalho.php";
    ?>


    <div class="container">
        <div class="titulo-principal">ESTOQUE DE PLACAS</div>
            <button value="VOLTAR" class="botao" onClick="history.go(-1)"><img src="imagens/iconevoltar.png" class="img-botao"> VOLTAR</button>
            <button value="ATUALIZAR" class="botao" onClick="history.go(0)"><img src="imagens/iconeatl.png" class="img-botao"> ATUALIZAR</button>
            <br>
            <br>
            <hr>
            <br>
<?php

    include "config/conectar.php";

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM ESTOQUECVISUAL";

                $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao,$sql);
?>
<?php if(mysqli_num_rows($resultado)>0): ?>
    <table border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse" width="60%">
                <tr class="cabecalho-tabela">
                  <td width="20%">TIPO</td>
                  <td>TRANSAÇÃO</td>
                  <td>TAMANHO</td>
                  <td>QUANTIDADE</td>
                  <td width='2%'></td>
                </tr>

    <?php
            while($linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
                $tipo = $linha['TIPO'];
                $transacao = $linha['TRANSACAO'];
                $tamanho = $linha['TAMANHO'];
                $quantidade = $linha['QUANTIDADE'];
                echo"

                    <tr>
                      <td>$tipo</td>
                      <td>$transacao</td>
                      <td>$tamanho</td>
                      <td>$quantidade</td>
                      <td><a href='alterarestoqueplacas.php?id=$id'><img src='imagens/iconeditar.png' /></a></td>
                    </tr>

                ";
            }
     ?>
            </table>
                  <br>
                  <hr>
                  <br>
                  <br>

<?php endif; ?>
    <?php
    include "config/rodape.php";
    ?>

    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

*obs: não é uma boa pratica misturar o código desse jeito, procure separar *select*/logica da aplicação do *html*.